# Fatal error upon building maps app ios

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Getting an error, I've been searching all day on how to use Corelocation along with GoogleMaps. thought I already had it when i got an error at the GMScameraposition part of the code. basically i'm trying to get my location upon loading the view which is why most is within the viewdidload().

```
import UIKit
    import GoogleMaps
    import CoreLocation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


        var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

        var currentLocation: CLLocation!
        var long: Float64!
        var lat: Float64!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(lat,
                longitude: long, zoom:6)
            let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera)

            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = camera.target
            marker.snippet = "Hello World"
            marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
            marker.map = mapView

            self.view = mapView
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
        func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            currentLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation
            long = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
            lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please don't ask us to guess.

Comment: i'm sorry, for not mentioning it. "exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)" this is what appears to the side when i try to build

Comment: i read further into the error, and I think its the "long" and "lat" variables not having a value, then being passed to the GMSCameraPosition

Answer (score 0):

Your view loads before you have an updated location to fill your variables, so it's as you said in your comment, your long and lat variables have no value.

I wrote out the fixed viewDidLoad and didUpdateLocations functions for you here:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(0,
            longitude: 0, zoom:0) //this can be set to wherever you want your view to start at

        //UPDATE: changed the initializing frame to be equal to the view, instead of CGRectZero
        let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.view.frame, camera:camera)

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = camera.target
        marker.snippet = "Hello World"
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
        marker.map = mapView

        self.view = mapView
    }

    //updated! This will tell your camera to snap to your latest location once you've received it.
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLocation = locations.last
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: currentLocation.coordinate, zoom: 6, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: the "self.view = mapView" line  giving an "use of unresolved identifier 'mapView' ". i tried moving it below into the locationManager function, and it somehow disappeared but still no map is showing

Comment: Ahh, since mapView is created programmatically, we'll have to set a default camera view and have the camera update once the lat and long have been set. I've updated my post to reflect these changes.

Comment: I think we need to set mapView as a global variable, because i'm getting the same error as last time but on the "mapView.camera" line in the func locationManager.

Comment: That's correct, go ahead and add a global variable for the mapView and see if it works out.

Comment: ok i tried it out, no error which is a plus, but no map is appearing.

Comment: It may be because your frame for GMSMapView is set to CGRectZero.
Try replacing that with `self.view.frame` as I will update in my posted code.

Comment: i was able to make the map appear through the use of the UIView in the storyboard for the app. what I did was that i created an outlet and named it mapView to serve as the global variable

Comment: Nice, that's how I've done it in the past (wasn't sure if you needed to create it programmatically). Is everything working out for you now?

Comment: i haven't gotten the map to go to my location or even ask for permission to use location so i'm following this tutorial to hopefully find out what i'm doing wrong [link] (http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/)

Comment: That's a good idea if you're starting with Google maps from scratch. Here's another good tutorial if you want to get really solid on Google Maps: https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial    Anyways, my guess is you haven't set up your plist to allow authorization.
Go into your plist file and add a property named "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription". For the value, type whatever you'd like your text to say.